# ContentObserver onChange() on Android 2.x not get called

Tags: android, contentobserver

I have a `ContentObserver` which I have tested on android 4.x and it worked well. But when I tried it on android 2.x it doesn't work.

```
mContentObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                if (CardDAO.MANAGEMENT_URI.equals(uri) || SubjectDAO.MANAGEMENT_URI.equals(uri)
                        || LearningProgressDAO.MANAGEMENT_URI.equals(uri) || ActivationDAO.MANAGEMENT_URI.equals(uri)) {
                    onContentChanged();
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: How come you ask a question and answer it at the same time?

Comment: @Carnal there is a check-box on the bottom of the screen " Answer your own question "

Comment: I know that. But you answered it no more than a minute after you asked it. Since rare you came up with a solution that quick.

Comment: @Carnal I spend couple of hours to find the solution, the I decided to share my investigation result as question-answer.

Comment: Alright, cool! Because it says you asked it 2 hours ago. And your answer came 2 hours ago. That's why! But it's good you share your solution with others. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that there is no such method `public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri)` in android 2.x . The solution is to use method which is in old API `public void onChange(boolean selfChange)`

HERE is the difference between two versions

2.x:

```
private final class More ...NotificationRunnable implements Runnable {

        ...................

     public void run() {
         ContentObserver.this.onChange(mSelf);
     }
 }
```

4.x:

```
private final class NotificationRunnable implements Runnable {

       ................................

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ContentObserver.this.onChange(mSelfChange, mUri, mUserId);
    }
}
```